# MongoDB details are not showing in phpinfo() in Linux (debian)

Tags: php, mongodb, debian

Mongo details are not showing in phpinfo() in Linux debian. I have in `php.ini`: `extension=mongo.so`. I already installed it.

I use VPS and I connect to it with Putty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do the steps at installation tutorial

http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php

Comment: Also restart your PHP web server

Comment: How can I restart my PHP server?

Comment: What do you use ? Apache with mod_php or nginx with php-fcgi ?

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Worked you're the best Community!